# Android 13 / API 33: create textfile in External Storage Folder "DOCUMENTS" and write data to it

Tags: android, file, stored-procedures, fragment

There are hundreds of posts dealing with the creation of text files in internal and external storage and how to store data in such files, but for external storage none of them are obviously working under Android 13 / API 33 anymore. A typical coding is:

```
public void WriteToFile(String myFile, String content){
    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    File newDir = new File(path + "/" + myFile);
    try{
        if (!newDir.exists()) {
            newDir.mkdir();
        }
        FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(new File(path, myFile));
        writer.write(content.getBytes());
        writer.close();
        Log.e("TAG", "Wrote to file: "+myFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Under Android 13 the above code snippet throws IOException, obviously because "newDir.mkdir()" does not create a new file under "DOCUMENTS" anymore, but instead creates a new folder with the name "myFile" under the folder "DOCUMENTS". As the new folder has no included file, the following command "FileOutputStream" has wrong parameters and throws the exception.

There are many other posts dealing with specific new procedures regarding media files under Android 13, but such do not cover documents. Posts which refer to the new procedures for documents using a user interaction through a "DirectoryPicker" do not cover usage in a fragment or explain how any result from the choice could be used in next codelines to fill in data in the new text file.

Therefore question is: How to modify above code snippet to work under Android 13, API 33, within a fragment in order just to create, open and write text into a file under the visible directory "documents" on an Android tablet? And, in case of mandatory user interaction: What is the procedures/coding within a fragment to interact with user, collect his selection and following steps out of this reaction to create and write to new file?

I tried more than 20 different solutions dealing with the request to write to a file in external storage under Android 13 provided by many different experts on different websites, but all of them either seems to be not valid for Android 13 / API 33 anymore, are not working within an fragment or do not provide a workable solution. Hopefully someone has already made experience with file handling from a fragment under new Android version.

Regarding information that code solution never could have worked even before: Please refer to thread 73045965 in which exactly same code is listed under "working solution" or similar code snippet at end of threat 72273850. Question remains: How to create and access file from a fragment, because this most probably is different from access from any Main_Activity (example: Toast.makeText(this, myText, ...) will work from any Main_Activity whereas same code within Fragment provides a "Cannot resolve method `makeText`... error; in Fragment it requires for any reasons to use "Toast.makeText(getActivity(); myText, ...) instead.

Comment: Yes your code is completely wrong and will not work on any Android version. You first create a directory and then try to open a stream for that directory. That will not go.

Comment: And it should be: 
        if (!newDir.exists()) 
           if(! newDir.mkdir()) return;

Comment: `obviously because "newDir.mkdir()" does not create a new file under "DOCUMENTS" anymore, ` mkdir() never created files. It only creates a directory. This has been so allways.

Comment: Have you got answer? I need the same.